# Whats the standard naming convention for readonly static logger field?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, nlog

I define all NLog instances in the solution like this:

```
private readonly static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

In all NLog examples, the logger field is Camel cased:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10631/Introduction-to-NLog

However, in Microsoft documentation they recommend to name all readonly static fields using Pascal case:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229043%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

In addition StyleCop has a rule with the same Pascal convention:
http://www.stylecop.com/docs/SA1311.html

So what would be the best convention for this scenario?

Comment: There is no correct answer to that. *It depends*. Just stick the convention you and your team feel comfortable with.

Comment: There must be SOME standard or recommendation right?

Comment: It sounds like you did your research, and your results were `it depends on which site you reference`.  I don't think anyone is going to provide any extra non-opinionated help

Comment: Isnt naming conventiom based on opinions in its base?

Answer (score 4):

The naming conventions always seemed a bit blurry to me, and Microsoft doesn't seem to follow them to the letter too.

Based on Resharper's naming conventions for private fields (which are based on StyleCop I believe):

```
 -private static readonly Type Name
 -private readonly Type _name
```

I personally usually go with the naming conventions offered by Resharper because they seem to follow Microsoft's naming as closely as it can, and it offers consistency for the whole codebase (if you screw it up, it will tell you).

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Others have noted, coding standards are kind of like religion.  So I have my personal preference below (based on my experience and research over the years).

I personally like `private, static` to be lowercase and backing fields prefixed with an underscore, like below:

```
private static readonly Type log
private readonly Type _log
```

Since you mentioned StyleCop, if you're just getting started, I'd stick with what StyleCop has by default and see if you like it.  Personally, I use [.editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org) with all my projects so there's no confusion between developers.  The config below is for setting the above suggestions (and disabling the StyleCop rules).

```
[*.{cs,vb}]


# camelCase and PascelCase
dotnet_naming_style.pascal_case_style.capitalization = pascal_case
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case_style.capitalization = camel_case

# camelCase with _ prefix
dotnet_naming_style._camelCase.capitalization = camel_case
dotnet_naming_style._camelCase.required_prefix = _

# Private Static Fields is camelCase (e.g. log)
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_field_symbol.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_field_symbol.applicable_accessibilities = private
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_static_field_symbol.required_modifiers = static

dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_field_naming.symbols = private_static_field_symbol
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_field_naming.style = camel_case_style
dotnet_naming_rule.private_static_field_naming.severity = suggestion

# SA1311: Static readonly fields should begin with upper-case letter
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1311.severity = none

# Private Fields is _camelCase (backing fields)
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_field_symbol.applicable_kinds = field
dotnet_naming_symbols.private_field_symbol.applicable_accessibilities = private

dotnet_naming_rule.private_field_naming.symbols = private_field_symbol
dotnet_naming_rule.private_field_naming.style = _camelCase
dotnet_naming_rule.private_field_naming.severity = suggestion

# SA1309: Field names should not begin with underscore
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1309.severity = none
```

P.S I also prefer the `log` name over `logger` which was the standard with `log4net`.  With newer logging libraries, that's changed to `logger`.
I personally prefer reading `log.Info(...)`, but I've used logging libraries with methods `.LogInfo(...)`.  In that case, I use `logger.LogInfo(...)`.  I believe the standard has changed since [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs)

Comment: I should make this an answer